# Where can I download Safari for Windows?

Tags: safari, windows

This sounds like an absurd question, I know, but when I go to:

http://www.apple.com/safari/

There isn't a download link! I'm sure it used to be there :-/

Here's what I see:

[image]

Scrolling further just has more features. No link!

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Safari on Windows is no longer supported by Apple.

Safari 5 (from 2010) is available via Apple's KB. The original page no longer exists, but [the EXE](http://appldnld.apple.com/Safari5/041-5487.20120509.INU8B/SafariSetup.exe) is still hosted.

According to [9to5mac](http://9to5mac.com/2012/07/25/apple-appears-to-currently-be-passing-on-safari-6-0-features-for-windows-pcs/), it seems that have Apple decided to stop producing Safari for Windows, so Safari 5 is all that's likely to be available moving forward.

Comment: The link no longer works. But as of writing, [this web.archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20210413145735/http://appldnld.apple.com/Safari5/041-5487.20120509.INU8B/SafariSetup.exe) link does still work ... and installs OK. (But obviously don't get your hopes up too much about it working well these days, was trying it out for testing purposes and whilst it loads a simple page such as the Google home page to an extent, it couldn't load my locally hosted page).

Answer (score 63):

The Windows version was discontinued, but the latest version (5.1.7) can still be downloaded directly from Apple as of 2021-04-13:

http://appldnld.apple.com/Safari5/041-5487.20120509.INU8B/SafariSetup.exe

It is also available on archive.org:

http://web.archive.org/web/20210413145735/http://appldnld.apple.com/Safari5/041-5487.20120509.INU8B/SafariSetup.exe

Comment: An older version is available here: http://appldnld.apple.com.edgesuite.net/content.info.apple.com/Safari3/061-4211.20071221.tGtgf/Safari304BetaSecUpdateSetup.exe

Answer (score 19):

There is no link to Safari for Windows because Apple stopped making it. If you want a copy of Safari for Windows you have to download the installer somewhere, or retrieve it from your backup.

**Update:** This link still works: [SafariSetup.exe](http://appldnld.apple.com/Safari5/041-5487.20120509.INU8B/SafariSetup.exe)

Comment: BAD IDEA to install this old thing; it's riddled with security holes, and does not support modern web site SSL protection, so more and more sites will not even load at all in it anymore.

Comment: @cnd The only reason any of us are downloading this stupid is browser is so that we can support our clients.

Comment: @mpen now that you know it is stupid to have this outdated browser, it is your duty to let your clients know. If you are worried about osX users, they'll be very few to still have an SL. If you really want to support your users, reproduce their environment the best you can (the least being an up-to-date VM).

Answer (score 10):

Like the others have said, Apple has ceased development for it. The latest Windows version is 5.1.7 and you can find it in several places including wordsoftech.com (https://www.wordsoftech.com/download-safari-for-windows/)

It will give you warnings galore, that its not the latest most secure browser, but if you must run it for some reason - there it is.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to still use Safari on Windows PC.

1. Using a cross-browser testing tool
2. Installing Safari 5.1.7 (The last supported version)

Since it is not safe to use dated version, the cross-browser testing tool is the best way if you just want to test your projects.

However, if you still want to install the last supported version of Safari, you can find the [download link to Safari for Windows here](https://www.geekdashboard.com/safari-browser-for-windows/).

**Warning**: Don't use the old version of Safari as your daily driver. It is not secure and pain to your eyes.