# Why can't I download Safari for Windows from Apple?

Tags: safari, windows

I'm not asking *where* or *if*, I'm asking *why can't I*.

Is it not in Apple's interest to make their browser available to Windows and other operating systems?

I'm asking as a web developer who wants to make sure I'm facilitating Safari users and their browser experience.

Third party "freeware" (read "bloatware"/"malware") download sites are offering downloads but can I not source the latest browser version directly from Apple?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I download Safari for Windows?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68836/where-can-i-download-safari-for-windows)

Comment: @dwightk What part of the **VERY FIRST SENTENCE** of my question is ambiguous? This very clearly isn't a duplicate question.

Comment: Apple stopped making Safari for Windows about 3 years ago, I'm afraid. Only way to test for it now is to use it on a Mac. As to why, who would know except Apple?

Comment: @Tetsujin You've outlined the WHAT and the HOW. I've asked for the WHY. Thanks either way.

Comment: @ClarusDignus **only Apple can provide an answer to your question.** Consider providing feedback to Apple via https://www.apple.com/feedback/ or opening a Technical Support Incident through the Developer Program to engage an Apple staff member on the subject.

Comment: @GrahamMiln I asked for the specific reason Apple discontinued Windows support for Safari. There's a definitive, objective and non-opinionated answer to this that reflects Apple's conscious decision. If other members do not know the answer, that's fine but they shouldn't get to mark my question as opinion-based simply because the only response they can fathom, in lieu of the required answer, is an opinion. If you don't know, you don't know. That doesn't mean I asked for an opinion. This is very basic reasoning.

Comment: Why is this closed?  I tried to download safari for windows and had the same problem.  I think closing this was based on opinion.  I think the question was based on reality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple most likely stopped Safari for Windows due to it's small marketshare on Windows and lack of explicit reason to continue it. The browser never had anything special and didn't provide any source of income either. Chrome and Midori both did WebKit on Windows anyway ( at the point of discontinuation ).

Nonetheless they still keep up the WebKit Project with Nightlies( basically Safari ), so if you want a Safari-like experience and the latest features on Windows, I believe building WebKit Nightly would be your best bet :

- http://nightly.webkit.org
- http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/BuildingOnWindows

Comment: I appreciate the information but you haven;t answered my question.

Comment: Right I shall update right away !

Comment: Do you have an opinion on the link provided by Pratika Rana (see [his answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/198003/138263) to my question)?

Comment: The link is an outdated version of Safari, probably terrible for developer tests. Of course it is however a legitimate version of Safari 5.

Comment: In addition; Apple has no reason to compete in the browser market share battle because there is no motive for them. Apple is mainly a hardware company, not a major player in the software industry. Google Chrome is still running because Google runs ... Well the Google Search Engine, which its main source of revenue. Since Google is the default search engine on Chrome, it brings them more revenue. In addition, since all Google revenue is gained through the Web, it makes sense to help the Web Browser industry & in turn themselves.

Answer (score 4):

Who says you can't download Safari for Windows? Get it directly from the Apple servers.

http://appldnld.apple.com/Safari5/041-5487.20120509.INU8B/SafariSetup.exe

Comment: Is this legitimate and safe? Can you provide any context regarding how you've come to know this?

Comment: Yes, it is directly from Apple.

Comment: I appreciate the link but you haven't answered my question. This is an obscured method. Why isn't Apple OPENLY offering (and inviting use thereof) their browser to Window users?

Comment: @ClarusDignus Apple is not providing the link directly, because they ceased Safari development after 5.1.7. They barely make any Windows software other than iTunes and iCloud. There is no point providing an ancient version of Safari on Apple website.

Comment: Why do you reckon they ceased development? Why not offer an up-to-date browser version for Windows? I can't understand why Apple don't choose to compete in the browser market especially since it would be a gateway to other Apple products and services. It's not like they don't have the money, resources or marketing power.

Comment: @ClarusDignus Only Apple would be able tell you that why exactly they stopped making Safari for Windows.