# I am a windows user, want to build a safari extension

Tags: safari, windows, safari-extensions

I am a windows user, want to build a safari extension, But i want to first know is there any way to test my extension in windows ? what is the latest version of safari for windows that apple support and if i build the extension on this version is that will run correctly on the latest safari version ?

Comment: I don't see any practical way to do this without a modern version of Safari to test on. I'd recommend purchasing a cheap Mac Mini or an old Macbook on eBay. It also isn't impossible to use Virtualbox, but it will require a substantial time investment to set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of Safari for Windows is [5.1.7](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68836/where-can-i-download-safari-for-windows).

Extensions are made with HTML, CSS and JavaScript, so depending on the exact functionality you want in your extension, it should work on all Safari versions that support extensions. Extensions were introduced in Safari 5.0.1.

For more information, see [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH1-SW1).